# MBProgressView is not working on UICollectionView for waiting in iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, mbprogresshud

MBProgressView is not working on UICollectionView for waiting in iOS
 it's working fine in other view controllers but when i used in uicollection view    controller it is not appering on screen, Please give me a solution for it.

> Please Check the Below Link

[UICollectionVIEW Code](http://paste.ofcode.org/L7KGtcSJUqUEH7AKTrRiKY)

Answer (score 0):

Try add to superview:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.collectionView.superview animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE**

Okay, I've examined your code, it's little bit messed up.
What happens here:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

       // You about to show HUD in your current VC views hierarchy
      MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.collectionView.superview animated:YES]; 
        hud.labelText = @"Loading...";
      // But immediately switching to another. Current VC will be off screen.
      // You will not see your HUD
      [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
...
```

Then:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"viewDidDisappear in Main Page");
    //  Looks like you want to hide your HUD here.
    // This code will be called right after [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1],
    // cause current with gonna disappear.
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];   
}
```

So, if you **really** want to see HUD (it's not clear how long it should be visible):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
      MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.tabBarController.view];
     //  hide after 4 seconds
     [hud hide:YES afterDelay:4];

...
```

Comment: Hi Orkenstein, I have added same thing in "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" method in uicollection view but still it is not appearing on View @orkenstein

Comment: @Koteswar, you switching to another tab right after cell was selected. What behavior you expect?

Comment: After Selecting cell, the MBprogressHUD should show Loading... until next view will apper

Comment: Thanks for Reply @orkenstein , but same thing the MBProgressHUD not appearing on UiCollectionView but appearing on the next coming View. Please Help me by  solution, I have to submit app to App Store

Comment: You are switching to another tab, right? The entire hierarchy with `UICollectionView` disappears. What do you expect?
What does it mean *next coming view*? Provide a screenshot at least.